# Highcharts, highlight point, without using click event?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I need to highlight a column in my bar chart.
I found this example http://jsfiddle.net/shawson/CkkbF/8/

They're using `this.update({ color: '#f00' }, true, false)`
 in the click event.

My question is, how do I get `this` so I can change the color, without a click event? What is `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkkbF/23/).  You can add colors into the data when you are creating it like this:

```
data: [29.9, {y: 34.4, color: 'red'}, {y: 176.0, color: '#aaff99'}, 135.6 ......
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look the [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data.color) you will see that each point can be a `number`, `array` of `numbers` or `object`.
When it's an `object` you can set `color`, `dataLabels`, `events`, `id`, `marker`, `name`, `x` and `y`.
So, this case you have to pass an `object` to the `point` which you want to set the `color`.
**`this`  refers the clicked point and not the `chart`.** [Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click)

If you log `this` you will see that. [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FQGBv/)

When you bind the event to the `point`, `this` refers the `point`.
When you bind the event to the `serie`, `this` refers the `serie`.
When you bind the event to the `chart`, `this` refers the `chart`.